# two points and then finds the smallest circle and the smallest rectangle containing the points

Tags: java

Write a Java program that reads two points and then finds the smallest circle and the smallest rectangle containing the points.  Note that a circle is represented by its center and radius, and a rectangle by the two diagonal points – top-left and bottom-right corners.  For example, p1 = (0, 0) and p2 = (4, 3) are entered as input, your program will print C = ((2, 1.5), 2.5) and R = ((0, 3), (4, 0)). No if statement is allowed, but you may use built-in methods such as sqrt, pow, abs, max, and min.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner ( System.in);
    double cx, cy, cyx,c; 
    double p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y;
    System.out.print("Enter point 1, x ");//0
    p1x=in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter point 1, y ");//0
    p1y=in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter point 2, x ");//4
    p2x=in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter point 2, y ");//3
    p2y=in.nextDouble();

    cx= (p2x-p1x)/2;// (2,)
    cy=(p2y-p1y)/2;// (,1.5) 
    cyx= (p2x-p2y)+cy;// ((,),2.5)

    System.out.println((cx+","+cy)+","+cyx);
```

as far as radius, i am unsure. As well as unsure if the code would work, or i am over complicating things, or far off at all.

Comment: Tihs looks oddly familiar. Hmm , well it is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464333/two-points-find-smallest-circle-and-rectangle-points   ?

Comment: Radius will be half the distance between the two points.

Comment: I posted the other one as well. I fixed everything up and then reposted it to be able to see everything new.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest circle containing two points will have each point along the circle's circumference, with the center of the circle directly between those two points, meaning the circle's radius is half the distance between the points.

With the simplest definition, we could use `((x2 + x1) / 2, (y2 + y1) / 2)` as the centerpoint, and `sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2) / 2` as the radius. However, if we use [java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Double.html) to represent the circle, you need to have the top-left corner of the square containing the circle and the diameter of the circle.

The diameter is easy: twice the radius, or `sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)`.

To get the top-left corner of the containing square, subtract the radius from the x- and y-coordinate of the centerpoint:

```
double diameter = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
Point2D.Double center = new Point2D.Double((x2 + x1) / 2, (y2 + y1) / 2);
Point2D.Double tlCorner = new Point2D.Double(
    center.x - diameter / 2,
    center.y - diameter / 2
);
Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(
    tlCorner.x,
    tlCorner.y,
    diameter,
    diameter
);
```

The smallest rectangle containing two points uses those two points as opposite corners. Again, with the simplest definition we could just use the two input points as two corners of a rectangle. However, Java's rectangle classes expect the top-left corner, the width, and the height, not two points.

```
Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(
    Math.min(x1, x2),
    Math.min(y1, y2),
    Math.abs(x2 - x1),
    Math.abs(y2 - y1)
);
```